# How to calculate distance between points in R with negative and positive coordinate

Tags: r

I have the following data frame of cluster points and their corresponding coordinates:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(clusters = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), X = c(-54.6159770964014, 
-28.2872926332498, 52.8522393678039, -25.8140448004464, 38.9620763534183, 
70.8641808918484, -15.1724011440888, 40.730220888559, 9.24483114349649, 
-55.927722121683, -6.27401943653456, -64.5652744957147, 18.7919353226617, 
20.0562482846276, -15.9544504453054), Y = c(8.22248244829743, 
28.9054292231316, -34.6075657907431, -37.9486871165297, -12.736119840414, 
-3.14128802462344, -1.12492457003011, 21.0867357880599, -17.678289925719, 
40.2262495018696, 33.0017714263723, -24.491950293976, 56.579084048791, 
-47.9835978682792, 71.6687592084785)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))


dat
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    clusters      X      Y
#>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 1        -54.6    8.22
#>  2 10       -28.3   28.9 
#>  3 11        52.9  -34.6 
#>  4 12       -25.8  -37.9 
#>  5 13        39.0  -12.7 
#>  6 14        70.9   -3.14
#>  7 15       -15.2   -1.12
#>  8 2         40.7   21.1 
#>  9 3          9.24 -17.7 
#> 10 4        -55.9   40.2 
#> 11 5         -6.27  33.0 
#> 12 6        -64.6  -24.5 
#> 13 7         18.8   56.6 
#> 14 8         20.1  -48.0 
#> 15 9        -16.0   71.7
```

Visually it looks like this:

[image]

What I wanted to do is to calculate the distance between points.
This is my attempt using Euclidean distance:

```r
  dm <- dist(dat[-1])
  dm
```

The result is this:

```r
           1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14
2   33.48110                                                                                                                                  
3  115.68851 103.04137                                                                                                                        
4   54.41809  66.89985  78.73720                                                                                                              
5   95.89638  79.09802  25.90940  69.50985                                                                                                    
6  125.99367 104.20176  36.25682 102.75327  33.31374                                                                                          
7   40.53603  32.76923  75.81846  38.33059  55.36571  86.06021                                                                                
8   96.21012  69.45897  56.99823  88.95685  33.86904  38.66591  60.15364                                                                      
9   68.91337  59.82226  46.77827  40.49708  30.12540  63.31089  29.49941  49.94053                                                            
10  32.03064  29.86895 132.03477  83.77442 108.66962 134.00347  58.05959  98.53466  87.18026                                                  
11  54.32272  22.39116  89.81613  73.59198  64.32930  85.18581  35.26773  48.49089  53.00286  50.17652                                        
12  34.19390  64.55519 117.85244  41.02123 104.19267 137.10211  54.64132 114.73691  74.12393  65.29206  81.87428                              
13  87.90383  54.61030  97.34017 104.52365  72.19025  79.23409  66.95766  41.72523  74.86858  76.48818  34.41209 116.27956                    
14  93.46157  90.82412  35.41885  46.95512  39.99769  67.76635  58.62417  72.09802  32.17605 116.42397  85.15816  87.82175 104.57033          
15  74.29767  44.50619 126.60576 110.05997 100.69761 114.60374  72.79788  75.97166  92.83264  50.85758  39.86034 107.74922  37.88152 124.95382
```

I found the result is not consistent with the figure. For example
visually cluster 6 to 1 visually closer than cluster 6 to 2. 
But the distance calculated by `dist()` are:

```r
6 to 1,  distance =  125.99367 
6 to 2,  distance =  104.20176
```

What's the adequate way to calculate that so that the value is consistent with the plot?

Comment: Your issue is not with the distance matrix but with the plotting itself. If cluster 2 has a negative value for the `x` coordinates, how can it lie in the right-upper corner?

Comment: In the plot you look at the labelled points, however in the distance matrix the 1 to 15 is just an index. Order you dataframe first according to the label, e.g. `dat[order(as.numeric(dat$clusters)),]`

Comment: @CIAndrews How can I modify `dist()` object into correct label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you order your dataframe, you can get the distance matrix as you labelled it. Then it is inline with the visual plot.

```
dat1 <- dat[order(as.numeric(dat$clusters)),]
> dist(dat1)
           1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14
2   96.21531                                                                                                                                  
3   68.94239  49.95055                                                                                                                        
4   32.17082  98.55495  87.18599                                                                                                              
5   54.46979  48.58360  53.04058  50.18649                                                                                                    
6   34.55753 114.80661  74.18462  65.32268  81.88039                                                                                          
7   88.10836  42.02375  74.97536  76.54699  34.47016 116.28386                                                                                
8   93.72334  72.34725  32.56222 116.49266  85.21099  87.84452 104.57511                                                                      
9   74.72713  76.29347  93.02633  51.10278  40.06054 107.79097  37.93428 124.95782                                                            
10  34.66964  69.91816  60.23042  30.46562  22.94263  64.67899  54.69264  90.84614  44.51743                                                  
11 116.11990  57.70441  47.45742 132.22019  90.01631 117.95846  97.42233  35.54568 126.62155 103.04622                                        
12  55.51872  89.51715  41.48510  84.15554  73.92415  41.45771 104.64317  47.12519 110.10085  66.92974  78.74355                              
13  96.64427  35.61056  31.74177 109.04167  64.82483 104.42754  72.43916  40.30899 100.77702  79.15489  25.98647  69.51704                    
14 126.66256  40.48522  64.25939 134.37608  85.65992 137.33531  79.54270  68.03145 114.71276 104.27851  36.38072 102.77273  33.32874          
15  42.88554  61.54235  31.84674  59.09243  36.65805  55.37756  67.43388  59.04060  73.04473  33.14849  75.92390  38.44781  55.40182  86.06602
```

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested in comments I'd rather question the plot than the distance matrix. Whit correct plotting method the results are consistent to your `"dist"` object.

```
plot(dat[, 3:2], type="n")
text(dat[, 3:2], labels=rownames(dat))
```

[image]